# How do you use Rails 5.2 wrap_parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

I have a Rails 5.2 app built as API only. I am using Postman to test the endpoints. Currently, I am wrapping all of my JSON POSTS with the root element in order to get it to pass the 'strong parameters'. According to the Rails docs, however, with `wrap_parameters` set to accept JSON, I shouldn't have to be doing this, however, my POSTs fail if I don't. What am I doing wrong?

---

```
# users_controller.rb

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  .....

  # POST /users
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user
    else
      render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  .....

  private
  .....

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :is_admin, :is_agent)
    end
end
```

---

```
# config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb

ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
  wrap_parameters format: [:json]
end
```

---

[image]

If I wrap the JSON in a `user` it works just fine, however, according to the Rails docs, I shouldn't have to do that.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html

I have tried adding `wrap_parameters User` and `wrap_parameters :user` and `wrap_parameters format: [:json]` directly to the `users_controller.rb` but that doesn't do anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out. I had to add `wrap_parameters :user, include: %i[email password is_admin is_agent]` to the Users controller like so:

```
# users_controller.rb

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  wrap_parameters :user, include: %i[email password is_admin is_agent]

  .....

  # POST /users
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user
    else
      render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  .....

  private
  .....

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :is_admin, :is_agent)
    end
end
```

I still don't fully understand why, but, it works. The docs imply this should be happening automagically through the wrap parameters module.

Comment: Do all the parameters you are posting exist as columns on the User table? The docs mention "On Active Record models with no :include or :exclude option set, it will only wrap the parameters returned by the class method attribute_names". I kept hitting this issue myself where some of my parameters were wrapped and some weren't. Turns out this was the issue. Reading this was very helpful - https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the **parameter whitelisting.**

```
 def user_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :is_admin, :is_agent)
 end
```

Here , user key is required. As per the security point of view, its a good feature in RoR to whitelist the parameters

If you write only  `params.permit(:email, :password, :is_admin, :is_agent)` , then you same request will work but **removing the user object is not recommended.**

Comment: I was under the impression from reading the docs that the entire point of the `wrap_parameters` module is that it automatically wraps your parameters with the classes object. From the docs: `If you enable ParamsWrapper for :json format, instead of having to send JSON parameters like this:

{"user": {"name": "Konata"}}

You can send parameters like this:

{"name": "Konata"}`

Comment: Have you restarted your server after creating intitializer file?

Comment: Yes, I restart the server after any changes I make to any of the code, even when it may not be necessary. I found that avoids a lot of headache. the `wrap_parameters` initializer is already in rails by default, however.

Comment: This is incredibly inconsistent. Wraps on production, but not test or development. Parameter vanish without a trace.

Comment: @NathanCrause I couldn't understand why rails doesnt wrap in test either. Turns out its because the parameters aren't being recognized as json. Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57451199