# Controller `params` behaving differently on test environment vs. development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using strong parameters for my `ShareOptions` controller, like so:

```
def share_option_params
  params.require(:share_option).permit(:public_read, :team_read, :team_write)
end
```

As you can see, `:share_option` is required, so when I test PUT with the attributes directly in a JSON body like this: `{ public_read: true }`, my test correctly fails because they're not nested under `share_option`. Using `binding.pry`, this is the output of `share_option_params`:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"public_read"=>"true", "format"=>:json, "controller"=>"api/share_options", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"553"} permitted: false>
```

However, this is not the case with my JS frontend where the same request is successful. There, I'm sending `{ public_read: true }` directly, not nested. In this case, it appears as if `share_option` is automatically added, here the output of `share_options_params`:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"public_read"=>true, "format"=>:json, "controller"=>"api/share_options", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"332", "share_option"=>{"public_read"=>true}} permitted: false>
```

At this point, I'm suspecting that Rails is doing something behind the scenes. But it's not clear to me at all as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out Rails allows you to omit the root element of your request when making *correct* JSON requests. In my case, my test wasn't encoding correctly as JSON, so this behavior wasn't occurring.

More information here: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#json-parameters

> […] if you've turned on config.wrap_parameters in your initializer or called wrap_parameters in your controller, you can safely omit the root element in the JSON parameter. In this case, the parameters will be cloned and wrapped with a key chosen based on your controller's name. So the above JSON request can be written as […]

To avoid this going forward, I plan on wrapping my params in my helper method for tests:

```
def json_request(params)
  {
    params: params.to_json,
    headers: { 'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json' }
  }
end
```